# PHP MYSQL JOIN: Two Similar Tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

Am trying to join two tables with the same column but different values but each time i output it duplicates.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
                    $dept = $_SESSION['department'];
                  $dept1 = strtolower($dept);
                  $dept2 = str_replace(" ", "_", $dept1);
                $dept4 = "$dept2" . "_200";
                  $dept = $_SESSION['department'];
                  $level = $_SESSION['level'];
                  $level2 = str_replace (" ", "_", $level);

                  if($level ="200_level") {
                    $query = " SELECT * FROM $dept2 Join $dept4";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $query = " SELCT * FROM $dept2";

                    }
                  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('<div       class="header5"small_font">Your Courses are not available yet. Pls contact the ICT Unit</div>');
                      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
                        $id = $row['id'];
                   $course = htmlspecialchars($row['course_name']);
                 $code = htmlspecialchars($row['course_code']);
                   $status = $row['status'];
                   $unit = htmlspecialchars($row['unit']);   

   ?>
```

Comment: Could you reduce your code to just the query? It is a lot easier to answer that way, and you should still be able to use the answer all the same. (I do believe it can be done using a union, but currently I have to put a lot of effort into seeing what your code does...)

Comment: How this has anything to do with PHP? I mean, yes, you're getting some values with PHP, but this is just a SQL problem IMHO.

Comment: Wat am trimg to do is to select values from two tables that has the same columns but different values.
i tried:

SELECT * FROM $dept2 JOIN $dept4


It outputs but duplicates $dept4 ignoring $dept2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the contents of two tables with the same columns, a [MySQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) should help

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

Like so:

```php
 $query = "(SELECT * FROM $dept2)
            UNION
           (SELECT * FROM $dept4)";
```